# How to get the decrypted string back from a JTextfield

Tags: java, string, swing, rsa, jtextfield

I have implemented rsa Encryption and Decryption in Java which works totally fine. But my problem is, when I write my encrypted string to a JTextField, I can't get the correct value back out of the JTextField in order to decrypt the message again.

Here is my code, I believe I am doing something wrong at the conversion of my values (`byte[]` and string):

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String message, PublicKey pk) {
    Cipher cipher= null;
    
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    byte[] chiffrat = null;
        
    try {
        chiffrat = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return chiffrat;
}

public static String decrypt(byte[] chiffrat, PrivateKey sk) 
{
    byte[] dec = null;
    Cipher cipher = null;
    
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try {
        dec = cipher.doFinal(chiffrat);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return new String(dec);
}
```

And in my Window class:
Writing encrypted string in my TextField

```
JButton btnEncrypt = new JButton("Plaintext -> RSA");
    btnEncrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txtEncryptionRSA.setText(new String(rsa.encrypt(pwboxEncryptionPlain.getText(), rsa.key.getPublic())));
        }
    });
```

This writes `` d¿Åád6×Ãö† G0|ôw;-3—?Ó^xudC\Ö>Ós`H9ÅóÛ`¥ `` in my TextField.

Trying to decrypt and write in another TextField:

```
JButton btnDecrypt = new JButton("RSA -> Plaintext");
    btnDecrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            byte[] encryptedmsg = txtEncryptionRSA.getText().getBytes();
            
            System.out.println(encryptedmsg);
            
            pwboxEncryptionPlain.setText(rsaClass.decrypt(encryptedmsg, rsa.key.getPrivate()));
        }
    });
```

This prints out: `[B@abd4af7` and Encryption fails.

Comment: You can't do it like that. You can't turn an byte array containing arbitrary binary content into a `String`. You'll need to Base64-encode it and use that. e.g. `txtEncryptionRSA.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encode(rsa.encrypt(pwboxEncryptionPlain.getText(), rsa.key.getPublic())));`

Comment: Your encryption output is a byte array that is not suitable for printing (think of hex 0 character). You should use a Base64 encoding and decoding for a string representation.

Comment: Thank you both so much! It worked.
For anyone else wondering, this is my code now:

`txtEncryptionRSA.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.encrypt(pwboxEncryptionPlain.getText(), rsa.key.getPublic())));`

and: `byte[] encryptedmsg = Base64.getDecoder().decode(txtEncryptionRSA.getText());
       
       pwboxEncryptionPlain.setText(rsaClass.decrypt(encryptedmsg, rsa.key.getPrivate()));`

Comment: RSA is not suitable for direct en/decryption of texts. If you want to use RSA use a hybrid (RSA+AES) based encryption scheme. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem